# Executing UIKit in background thread in swift

Tags: ios, multithreading, uikit

What will happen, when we will execute UIKit on background thread.
Will the app chrash or the UI is unresponsive . can anyone explain it to me .

Comment: Try it. See what happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per `Apple's guideline`, we should not execute any `UIKit` element update in the background thread, the results are unpredictable or it will through error, while running the app, For reference please refer [Main Thread Checker](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/code_diagnostics/main_thread_checker)